# Time out waiting for emulator to come online in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new in android and trying to run a simple `Hello world!` program using android studio. I defined an AVD which is a Pixel device with API version 28 (`Pie`). When I run the program, the emulator gets up, but it doesn't load the application. I have tried following, but none of them worked:

1. Restarting `avd` server from command-line.
2. Changing skin to `QVGA`.
3. Creating a new emulator.
4. Setting graphics to software.

Any idea on the issue?

Comment: did you enable USB Debugging mode in developer options?

Comment: @majidghafouri, on the emulator or the IDE? To be clear, I'm not using a real device, I am using an emulator.

Comment: well, do you see your emulator in Logcat tab?

Comment: @majidghafouri, yes. I do.

Comment: Please close your avd, then Right click on your avd in "AVD MAnager"and Wipe data for the virtual device and run it again then test it.

Comment: @majidghafouri, tried it multiple times; did not work.

Comment: maybe the adb causes this issue. It is possible that you have multiple adb in your processes. Close AVD and "End Process" the adb in task manager. Then test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200931/discussion-between-zeinab-abbasimazar-and-majid-ghafouri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not enabled USB Debugging in your AVD.
Try this steps:

**1- go to your AVD setting**

**2- System**

**3- About Device**

**4- Multiple Clicks on Build Number**

**5- Go back to setting**

now you see Developer Options

**6- goto developer options**

**7- check USB Debugging**

Hope to be useful

Comment: nice to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled USB debugging inside the emulator?

Before you create an Android emulator, you need to install an Android system image that your emulators can use.

**Note:** **If you installed the Android SDK and NDK during RAD Studio installation, a valid Android system image (such as Android 4.2.2 API 17) should already be shown as Installed in the Android SDK Manager. In this case, you do not need to install another Android system image.**

Still, if you are not able to run the emulator then try this [Memu Emulator](https://www.memuplay.com/)
This is a very small and simple emulator to use and install. It works perfectly on every pc.

Comment: First of all, I want to use android studio, not anything else. Secondly, I have created my AVD correctly, I can see it running, but the app is not loading on that. And at last, I tried to activate developer mode on the emulator as it is activated in a real device, but i can't see the developer options inside settings. Can you explain me how exactly should I do it?